# custom style dialog box codenameone

Tags: codenameone

how to change style dialog box... like changing background etc its very confusing

```
 Dialog d = new Dialog();
            d.setUIID("abc");
            d.setDialogUIID("abc");
            d.getContentPane().setUIID("myDialog");
            Label popupOutfitSaved = new Label("There are no recent searches");
            popupOutfitSaved.setUIID("DialogLabel");
            d.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            d.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, popupOutfitSaved);
            d.setTransitionInAnimator(CommonTransitions.createFade(1000));
            d.setTransitionOutAnimator(CommonTransitions.createFade(800));
            d.getStyle().setOpacity(0);
            d.getStyle().setBgColor(0xff0000);  //why doesn't it work
            d.setTimeout(5000);
            d.showPopupDialog(c);
```

I change tintcolor also bt in vain

```
@Override
    protected void beforeMain(Form f) {
           f.setTintColor(0xccff99);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All of the stuff you did other than `setTintColor` is unrelated.

`setTintColor` is an AARRGGBB color not an RRGGBB color as you listed. So something like:

```
f.setTintColor(0x7fccff99);
```

Should work fine.

Comment: thankyou so much.. 1 more thing the whole screen is covered with bg color while using f.setTintColor(0x7fff0000), can't we setTintColor to the dialog box only... ??

Comment: TintColor is the transparent color overlay on the form before placing your dialog on top. Check my answer for ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You need to style DialogBody, DialogTitle, DialogContentPane and Dialog UIID. It's more convenient to do this in GUI Builder than in code.

Comment: There is... And can be found when you click "Add A New GUI Element"